# AMDGPU-pro unmet dependancies when updating

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, amdgpu-pro

I was using AMDGPU-pro 17.10, decided to go for 17.50. the uninstall script that came with the packages seemed to uninstall correctly. Next i download 17.50 from the AMD website and attempted to install it. That's where the fun begins. It starts the process and then fails with this error.

```
$ ./amdgpu-pro-install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core (= 17.50-511655) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: amdgpu-dkms (= 17.50-511655) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-pro-core : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 glamor-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 gst-omx-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 ids-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libdrm2-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libgbm1-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm5.0-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libllvm5.0-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

tried installing amdgpu-core

```
amdgpu-core is already the newest version (17.50-511655).
amdgpu-core set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-dkms (= 17.50-511655) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so tried to install amdgpu-dkms

```
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms 17.50-511655 [5,578 kB]
(Reading database ... 465986 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (17.50-511655) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf', which is also in package amdgpu-pro-dkms 17.10-410326
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So then i tried

```
   $ sudo apt -f install
```

And i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,578 kB of archives.
After this operation, 127 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms 17.50-511655 [5,578 kB]
(Reading database ... 465986 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (17.50-511655) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf', which is also in package amdgpu-pro-dkms 17.10-410326
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so i check the logs at /var/dist-upgrade/apt.log

```
Log time: 2017-08-05 14:22:57.208973
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 4
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 4
Investigating (0) libomxil-bellagio0 [ i386 ] < 0.9.3-3ubuntu1 > ( universe/l$
Broken libomxil-bellagio0:i386 Conflicts on libomxil-bellagio0 [ amd64 ] < no$
  Considering libomxil-bellagio0:amd64 0 as a solution to libomxil-bellagio0:$
  Added libomxil-bellagio0:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libomxil-bellagio0:i386 via keep of libomxil-bellagio0:amd64
Investigating (0) libomxil-bellagio-bin [ i386 ] < 0.9.3-3ubuntu1 > ( univers$
Broken libomxil-bellagio-bin:i386 Conflicts on libomxil-bellagio-bin [ amd64 $
  Considering libomxil-bellagio-bin:amd64 -2 as a solution to libomxil-bellag$
  Added libomxil-bellagio-bin:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libomxil-bellagio-bin:i386 via keep of libomxil-bellagio-bin:amd64
Investigating (1) mesa-vdpau-drivers [ amd64 ] < 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 1$
Broken mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 Depends on libomxil-bellagio0 [ amd64 ] < non$
  Considering libomxil-bellagio0:amd64 0 as a solution to mesa-vdpau-drivers:$
  Removing mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 rather than change libomxil-bellagio0:amd$
Investigating (2) vdpau-driver-all [ amd64 ] < 1.1.1-3ubuntu1 > ( video )
Broken vdpau-driver-all:amd64 Depends on mesa-vdpau-drivers [ amd64 ] < 17.0.$
  Considering mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 2 as a solution to vdpau-driver-all:am$
  Added mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing vdpau-driver-all:amd64 via keep of mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64
Investigating (2) mesa-vdpau-drivers [ i386 ] < 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 1:$
Broken mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 Breaks on mesa-vdpau-drivers [ amd64 ] < 17.0.$
  Considering mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 6 as a solution to mesa-vdpau-drivers:$
  Holding Back mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 rather than change mesa-vdpau-drivers:$
 Try to Re-Instate (2) mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (3) mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
Done
Log time: 2017-08-05 14:23:11.848629
```

tried to install dependencies, but apt and dpkg wont let me do anything,i just keep getting unmet dependancy errors, even when trying to install the .deb.

Attempting to reinstall 17.10 gives me the same errors

Dont really know where to go from here, what do you all suggest?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `uname -a` into you post. Thank you for helping us help you!